# flutter passphrase in pubspec

Tags: dart, flutter

Is is possible to use `passphrase` in pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  customFramework:
  url: git@gitlab.com:nameandurl..
  ref: lkjdfksdjf
  path: package/nameofpackage
```

I get

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

And I am using `passphrase` which is the reason for the access problem. But then I need to add passphrase, I guess - but how?

Note: `passphrase` should probably not be in source code, but maybe there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pubspec.yaml syntax is wrong. It should be

```
dependencies:
  customFramework:
    git:
      url: git@gitlab.com:nameandurl..
      ref: lkjdfksdjf
      path: package/nameofpackage
```

If you use `git@...` paths (in contrary to `https://...`) setting up an SSH connection and connecting before running `pub get` should work.

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: To add more to the answer, I should say that once you are done with the configuration, run the `flutter pub get` command in the terminal rather than the IDE update button. For some reason, the IDE `Pub get` button couldn't load dependencies from my git@ssh.dev.azure.com but after I ran the above command manually then it was able to get dependencies again. From the command line, it is asking for the passphrase and caches it somewhere, I believe.